# How can I apply user filters to a selection in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba and am trying to create a simple macro to export some data to a text file. I have that working, however, when a user applies any filters that hide rows, it simply exports all data from the first row to the last row, disregarding anything filtered out. I have searched all over, but (probably from my lack of experience with vba) I cannot find anything that will work with both the user's filter and their selection. The thing is, I don't even know if filtered rows are considered by excel to be "hidden". I've also tried many methods other than what was listed below, such as .AutoFilter and .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), however neither of them work with Selection.

```
Sub old_export_for()
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
myFile = "C:\OUT\old_out_" + CStr(Format(Now(), "mmddhhmm")) + ".txt"
Set rng = Selection
Open myFile For Output As #1
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    If Not rng.Rows.Hidden Then
    j = 1
    cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
    Print #1, "Filename      : " + CStr(cellValue)
    j = 2
    cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
    Print #1, "File Size     : " + CStr(cellValue)
    j = 3
    cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
    Print #1, "Hostname      : " + CStr(cellValue)
    j = 4
    cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
    Print #1, "Date          : " + CStr(cellValue)
    j = 5
    cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
    Print #1, "Session ID    : " + CStr(cellValue),
    Print #1, vbNewLine + vbNewLine
    End If
Next i
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: how about `SpecialCells`? `Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` should do the trick (no hidden cells will be in `rng`

Comment: I feel like that should work. However, only the first selected row is exported.

Comment: I added a sample for `SpecialCells`... but to change the topic a bit: better use `&` instead of `+` for text... just to avoid errors in the future ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
If Not rng.Rows.Hidden Then
```

to

```
If Not rng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden Then
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Literally stared at this thing for hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just to show how I would put this with the `SpecialCells`:

```
Sub old_export_for()
  Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, xRow As Variant
  myFile = "C:\OUT\old_out_" + CStr(Format(Now(), "mmddhhmm")) & ".txt"
  Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  Open myFile For Output As #1
    For Each xRow In rng.Rows
      Print #1, "Filename      : " & CStr(xRow.Cells(1).Value)
      Print #1, "File Size     : " & CStr(xRow.Cells(2).Value)
      Print #1, "Hostname      : " & CStr(xRow.Cells(3).Value)
      Print #1, "Date          : " & CStr(xRow.Cells(4).Value)
      Print #1, "Session ID    : " & CStr(xRow.Cells(5).Value)
      Print #1, vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    Next i
  Close #1
End Sub
```

still, for a sub this short, I'd use something non-readable like this:

```
Sub old_export_for()
  Dim xRow As Variant, i As Long, str As String
  Open "C:\OUT\old_out_" + CStr(Format(Now(), "mmddhhmm")) & ".txt" For Output As #1
    For Each xRow In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows: For i = 1 To 6
      Print #1, Array("Filename      : ", "File Size     : ", "Hostname      : ", "Date          : ", "Session ID    : ", vbNewLine)(i - 1) & Array(CStr(xRow.Cells(i).Value), vbNewLine)(1 + (i < 6))
    Next: Next
  Close #1
End Sub
```

But do not do this :P

Comment: Thanks! The first example is much more reasonable.

Comment: As said... do not use the second one... it is just to confuse ppl (still, it works without errors) :P

Answer (score 1):

If this is not helpful, I will delete the answer.  Say we have AutoFiltered data in *Sheet1*.  This tiny macro will take the header row and all the visible data rows and copy them to *Sheet2*

```
Sub AutoFilterCopyVisible()
    Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste
End Sub
```

After running this, you can export *Sheet2*.  If *Sheet1* is like:

[image]

then *Sheet2* will have:

[image]

***Note:***

There is no autofiltering in the output sheet.

Comment: I need my results in plaintext more or less. I wouldn't say this isn't helpful though. Just a different case than mine.

Comment: @MacroPower  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Its not wrong in the first place... I wouldn't delete this answer... chances are high that someone with a problem which fits perfectly to your solution hits this question ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel ...................O.K..............I'll leave it in........... *(at least I did not get a down-vote)*

Comment: I would never downvote someone with connections to Gary.

Comment: @MacroPower  Especially as Gary is now in Heaven *(hopefully)*